# Delete Downstream ChangeLog Objects KafkaStreams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to delete records with the value null, in the downstream changelog, I know in the statestore they are deleted just by being null (tombstones), but when you do an aggregation on the KTable or Stream, they skip the null and don't delete it. I need to figure a way out to set a flag for deletion in the aggregation to let Kafka know the record can be deleted. Here is my code:

```
   public void deleteByEntity(String inputTopic, String target, String stateStoreName) {

      // Need to set property to true in application.properties
//      if ("true".equals(utils.getProperty(ApplicationConfigs.KAFKA_DELETE_BY_ENTITY))) {
      Materialized<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> storeName =
              Materialized.as(stateStoreName);

    StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, String> docStream = streamsBuilder.stream(inputTopic);

    KTable<?, ?> dataInTable =
        docStream
            .groupByKey()
            .reduce(
                (value1, value2) -> {
                  //                  System.out.println("aa");
                  if (value1.equals(target)) {
                    // If key equals target topic return null, creates tombstone deletes from
                    // statestore, sends null record downstream
                    return null;
                  }
                  return value2;
                },
                storeName);
    //    System.out.println(dataInTable);
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `return null` from your `Reducer` it will delete the data from the store *and* it will send a corresponding output record `<key,null>`. Hence, no downstream processing should be required.

Note that `null` keys and `null` values are only ignored for *input* record to `reduce()`.

Comment: Does the following code work for finding a key then deleting the object?if (value1.equals(target)) {
                      // If key equals target topic return null, deletes topic from statestore
                      return null;
                    }

Comment: When `Reducer#apply(...)` is called, you don't really know the key -- hence, you would need to copy the key into the value before you call `groupBy()`.

Comment: Ok, so virtually before I call groupByKey, I need to somehow get the key that I want to delete the value from, so if key is "a" and I want to null the value of "a" I would have to get that key value somehow?

Comment: Yes. And you need to put the key that you want to delete into the value of the message, such that `apply()` can read it and return `null`.

Comment: Ok I edited my initial code, to what I have changed it too over the past couple days. I think I understand that, thank you!

Comment: Note that `value2` is the value if of the input record, while `value1` is the current result for the key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203060/discussion-between-c2h50h-and-matthias-j-sax).

Comment: so value1 is equal to the key for the given record(value2), so if value1.equals(target) - return null should be correct

Comment: The problem is reduce maps to the values, when I want value1 to equal the key.  Check out this example, this is how I've been trying to do it for a different topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59204839/delete-entire-topic-from-state-store

Comment: You will need to copy the key into the value before you call `reduce()`...